# Input Output Relationship of Inverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework, inverting-amplifier

Can someone explain the input output relationship of below attached image ?

[image: Inverting Op-Amp]

Comment: What has your approach been so far?

Comment: Voltage divider followed by inverting amplifier. These are two of the simplest circuits you can get, have a search online.

Comment: What's the voltage on the - input of an inverting amplifier?

Comment: Voltage is not specified. It is generalized

Comment: No, I mean the voltage on the - input of the op amp itself, not Vin.

Comment: It is also not specified. Normally in Inverting Op-Amp if we don't have R1 and R2 the Voltage gain equals to Av =-R4/R3. But here due to voltage divider what it should be?

Comment: @Finbarr asked you a very important question that is the key to solving the problem.  The voltage on the - input doesn't HAVE to be specified, but it's a key piece of information.  If you don't know what it is you should review op-amp fundamentals.

Comment: So, if Av = -R4/R3 what must that tell you about -Vin of the op-amp or, if the op-amp open loop gain is 1 million, what would -Vin be under pretty much all normal linear situations.

Comment: My approach would be to transform Vin, R1,R2,R3 into a thevenin equivalent circuit, then use the new thevenin resistance as the new "R3a" after which your inverting op amp formula will work.

Comment: @JohnD I have seen this question somewhere without specifying the voltage on the input. That's why I am asking how to solve it without knowing the value of input voltage.

Comment: Understanding how the basic inverting amplifier circuit works is key to understanding this problem. @Andyaka has given you a big clue. You'll learn a lot more by working it out for yourself.

Comment: "I have seen this question somewhere without specifying the voltage on the input. " Again, not talking about the voltage marked Vin, but the voltage at the inverting input of the op-amp.  We all know what it is to a very close approximation without doing any calculations at all.  If you don't, you need to review op-amp fundamentals.

Comment: Learn the virtual open and virtual short rules, and everything can be derived quickly from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldvHc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ans.  Av=- R4 / (R1+R3//R2)

Answer (score 0):

The voltage at the i/p of the op-amp is not \$V_{in}\$ but the voltage across \$R_2\$. By considering virtual ground, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ are in parallel and total current supplied by the source can be given as \$\frac{V_{in}}{R_1+R_2||R_3}\$. Use current division and find the current through \$R_2\$. Once you find the voltage across \$R_2\$, find the o/p by using the gain for an inverting configuration.